# Selecionar coluna específica de arquivo .MDB no C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Preciso usar os dados de uma coluna específica em um arquivo `.MDB`. Consigo ler o arquivo, mas ele só me mostra primeira coluna, tentei mudar o `SELECT`, mudando o * pelo *nome da coluna*, mas não deu certo

Referencia: código do http://www.macoratti.net/Default.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AcessoMDB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                    //cria a conexão com o banco de dados
            OleDbConnection aConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\c066408\Desktop\Sprint\68\16417\BEC.MZ.BEX0.R007T.D0220.P0724.AL\BEC.MZ.BEX0.R007T.D0220.P0724.AL.mdb");

           //cria o objeto command and armazena a consulta SQL
            OleDbCommand aCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from SysTable", aConnection);

           try
              {
                aConnection.Open();
                //cria o objeto datareader para fazer a conexao com a tabela
                OleDbDataReader aReader = aCommand.ExecuteReader();

                Console.WriteLine("Os valores retornados da tabela são : ");

                //Faz a interação com o banco de dados lendo os dados da tabela
                while(aReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(aReader.GetString(1));
                }
                //fecha o reader
                aReader.Close();
                //fecha a conexao
               aConnection.Close();
                //pausa
                Console.ReadLine();
             }
            //Trata a exceção
            catch(OleDbException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Errors[0].Message);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que não deu certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando estritamente para o teu código.
Tu está consultando todas as colunas mas escrevendo apenas uma.

No teu while manda exibir as demais colunas, respeite os tipos de retorno da tua consulta, onde for string usar string onde for numérico usar Int.

```
//Faz a interação com o banco de dados lendo os dados da tabela
  while(aReader.Read())
  {
       Console.WriteLine(aReader.GetString(0));
       Console.WriteLine(aReader.GetString(1));
       Console.WriteLine(aReader.GetString(2));
       Console.WriteLine(aReader.GetInt32(3));
  }
```